# How to add new language Unicode range to Android OS

Tags: android, unicode

**Background**

- In Sri Lanka we use our own language call [Sinhala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhala_language)
- We have our own Unicode range(0D80 - 0DFF) and set of rendering rules for this language.
- But currently in Android phones not support this language(but Linux and windows support).
- We have build some temporary soloution using Javascript to read `Sinhala` in Andoid
- But we face issue when need to input by users.

**Question**

1. How to add new Unicode range inbuilt support to Android?
2. Do I need to request if from Google or can we do it our selves?
3. Do we need to request this from Android customizing bodies such as Samsung, HTC, Acer
4. How to create a Android keyboard that suitable to my language.

Appreciate all ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In middle east - in my country Iran - OEMs are solving this issue. They have released custom ROM specifically for middle east and supports all languages in this area (which are Arabic, Persian, Hebrew, etc.)

Don't worry if OEMs don't support your language yet. In this case look at this link "https://github.com/AhmedEssam/Better-Arabic-Reshaper.git" which is Arabic reshaper. You can get idea and do it yourself.